# Problem involving triangle. Find $x$ in the figure

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image: This is the triangle for the problem. I need to find x]
I need to find $x$ in the triangle above.

I tried to do basic things, like sum of a triangle's internal angles $= 180^\circ$ but I only found $2$ equations for $3$ variables

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why do you think that $x\in \mathbb N$?

Comment: Do you have any side lengths?

Comment: My guess is that this is a variant of the problem of adventitious angles. You can search for that; it has come up on this website several times.

Comment: @miracle173 It was given by my teacher. I thought maybe we would have 2 solutions and we could use that to eliminate one possibility.

Comment: @TobyMak No, I do not. That is all information given

Comment: @Daquisu No, you have not given any length. All congruent triangles are solution. So you can increase or decrease you triangle by arbitrary factors and can get another solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In triangle $ABC$ you have the following angles $\angle A=120^\circ$ (top corner), $\angle B=20^\circ$ (left corner) and $\angle C=40^\circ$ (right corner). Denote the central point with $D$ and introduce lengths $AD=a, BD=b,CD=c$.

By law of sines applied to triangles $ABD,ACD,BCD$:

$$a\sin20^\circ=b\sin10^\circ\tag{1}$$

$$a\sin100^\circ=c\sin(40^\circ-x)\tag{2}$$

$$b\sin10^\circ=c\sin x\tag{3}$$

From (1) and (2):

$$b=\frac{a\sin20^\circ}{\sin10^\circ}$$

$$c=\frac{a\sin100^\circ}{\sin(40^\circ-x)}$$

Replace that into (3):

$$\frac{a\sin20^\circ}{\sin10^\circ}\sin10^\circ=\frac{a\sin100^\circ}{\sin(40^\circ-x)}\sin x$$

$$\sin20^\circ \sin(40^\circ-x)=\sin100^\circ\sin x$$

$$\sin20^\circ \sin(40^\circ-x)=\cos10^\circ\sin x$$

$$2\sin10^\circ \cos10^\circ \sin(40^\circ-x)=\cos10^\circ\sin x$$

$$2\sin10^\circ \sin(40^\circ-x)=\sin x$$

Sometimes you have to make things more complicated before your are able to jump over the last hurdle: multiply the right side with $1=2\sin30^\circ$.

$$2\sin10^\circ \sin(40^\circ-x)=2\sin x\sin30^\circ$$

$$\cos(-30^\circ+x)-\cos(50^\circ-x)=\cos(x-30^\circ)-\cos(x+30^\circ)$$

$$\cos(50^\circ-x)=\cos(x+30^\circ)$$

For obviously acute angle $x$

$$50^\circ-x=x+30^\circ$$

$$x=10^\circ$$

No calculator needed.

Comment: Nice!... I'm looking for an answer without trigonometry, but this looks the easiest

Answer (score 0):

Using the same labeling as the author of the trig proof:

Cut off $BE$ on $BC$, such that $BE=BA$. Then, using the fact that $BD$ is the bisector of  $\angle B$, we can easily show that  $\triangle ADE$ is equilateral, so that $EA=ED$. Similarly, we can show that $\triangle AEC$ is isosceles (with base angles of $40^\circ$), so that $EA=EC$. Therefore $ED=EC$, so that, in $\triangle EDC, \angle EDC = \angle ECD = x$. 
But the external angle $BED (=\angle BAD) = 20^\circ$ , therefore $2x = 20^\circ$ ,
yielding that $x=10^\circ$.